# C# `[FromBody]` attribute bad unicode decoding for JSON

Tags: c#, json, unicode

I have the following code,

```
[HttpPost("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] JToken body)
{   
    return Json(body);
}
```

I tried `POST`ing with and without unicode character, both responds with the exact document, but the unicode ones doesn't decode correctly in C# debugger (it does not display correctly), nor does it do anything useful (`.ToString()` prints nothing.)

My Request:

```
POST /api/vendors HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:33000
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.2.5 (Macintosh; OS X/10.12.4) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 18

{
  "A":"你好"
}
```

My Response:

```
{"A":"你好"}
```

Under Visual Studio, it shows:
[image]

Comment: Are you setting your content type on the request in?

Comment: I used Postman, it does JSON already. I tried appending charset at the end. Didn't help.

Comment: Can you URLEncode and post as a string, then desearialize?

Comment: That's a workaround though, I kinda hope it works magically like that. I actually first tried to deserialize as custom structure, which works, until Unicode comes along.

Comment: Can you show us the request you're POSTing?

Comment: @Amy edited to include what i posted and what VS showed. Magically, the response is correct (which indicated it is parsed correctly anyway?)

Comment: I can't see the screenshot due to corporate firewall.  I **suspect** its parsing the character correctly, but the debugger visualizer doesn't know the character set, so the *visualizer* is wrong.

Comment: [this link](http://blogs.msmvps.com/gdicanio/2016/11/22/whats-wrong-with-my-utf-8-strings-in-visual-studio/) explains this VS behavior.